# need help using windows sockets to view all incoming packets

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, sockets, networking

I'm trying to create a program that can receive and display all incoming packets to my home network.  This is a just 'for fun' project, as I'm trying to get better at working with computer networks.

I found a couple of tutorials on working with sockets, and I'm trying to emulate what they're doing. (Working with [this](http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/c-c-sockets-faq-and-how-to-win-linux.56901/) (and the initialization stuff comes from [this](http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/sending-and-receiving-packets/)) tutorial at the moment).

I'm having some problems getting the code to work, however.  Here is the code I have thus far: (since I know I'm only going to use this on windows, I just omitted the other marcos for mac and unix)

```
#define PLATFORM_WINDOWS 1

#if defined(_WIN32)
#define PLATFORM PLATFORM_WINDOWS
#endif

#if PLATFORM == PLATFORM_WINDOWS
#include <WinSock2.h>
#endif

#pragma comment( lib, "wsock32.lib" );
#pragma comment( lib, "Ws2_32.lib" );

#include <iostream>

bool InitializeSockets()
{
#if PLATFORM == PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    WSADATA WsaData;
    return WSAStartup( MAKEWORD(2,2), &WsaData);
#else
    return true;
#endif
}


void ShutdownSockets()
{
#if PLATFORM == PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    WSACleanup();
#endif
}

void printIpPacket(unsigned char* data, int length)
{
    printf("-----------------Packet Begins-----------------\n");
    printf("IP Version: %i, Packet Size: %ibytes, Id: %i\n",
        (data[0]>>4), (data[2]*256)+data[3], (data[4]*256)+data[5]);

    printf("Fragment: %i, TTL: %i, HL: %iwds, Protocol: %i\n",
        ((int)(data[6]>>4)*256)+data[7], data[8], ((char)(data[0]<<4))>>4, data[9]);

    printf("Source: %i.%i.%i.%i, Destination: %i.%i.%i.%i\n",
        data[12], data[13], data[14], data[15],
        data[16], data[17], data[18], data[19]);

    //the data inside the packet starts at --> data+(((char)(data[0]<<4))>>2)
    //new data length --> length-(((char)(data[0]<<4))>>2)
    //continue printing the rest of the headers :o  

    printf("\n------------------Packet Ends------------------\n");  
}

int main()
{
    InitializeSockets();

    int thisSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP);

    int optVal = 1;
    setsockopt(thisSocket, IPPROTO_IP, 2, (char *)&optVal, sizeof(optVal));

    int inn = 1, outt;
    long rett;
    int err = WSAIoctl(thisSocket, 0x98000001, &inn, sizeof(inn), &outt, sizeof(outt), &rett, 0, 0);
    int a = WSAGetLastError();
}
```

I'm having some trouble getting the `WSAIoctl` function to work.  This code, which the tutorial claims will work, does not even compile.  I get the error:

```
error C2664: 'WSAIoctl' : cannot convert parameter 7 from 'long *' to 'LPDWORD'
```

So, I then changed the WSAIoctl function line to this:

```
int err = WSAIoctl(thisSocket, 0x98000001, &inn, sizeof(inn), &outt, sizeof(outt), (LPDWORD)&rett, 0, 0);
```

This compiled, but then WSAGetLastError() returned an error code of 10022, which according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) means an invalid argument.

So then I thought, "okay, instead of trying to force a conversion of the wrong type to the correct type, I guess I should just pass in the correct type."

So then I created a variable

```
LPDWORD rett = new DWORD;
```

Doing this, I compiled successfully, but I again received error code 10022.

At this point, I don't know what else to do.  Can someone help me get this program working?

Comment: Regarding your variable, is there something wrong with changing the type of the *variable* ? : `DWORD rett = 0;`, then passing `&rett` as you did before? And regarding your error. Regarding your *error*, if you going to be sniffing packets using `SIO_RCVALL` the socket should be `SOCK_RAW`, not `SOCK_STREAM`. I realize the [documentation for WSAIoctl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741621(v=vs.85).aspx) is extensive, but so is the power of the function itself. With great power... Anyway, best of luck.

Comment: So I created the DWORD and passed in its address as you said, and now I'm getting error code 10038: `Socket operation on nonsocket.
An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket. Either the socket handle parameter did not reference a valid socket, or for select, a member of an fd_set was not valid.`

Comment: Make sure that `thisSocket` created successfully. I presume you used SOCK_RAW. You need elevated privileges to do this.

Comment: @user58697 Ah, checking for errors on socket creation, I'm getting error 10013, meaing I do not have the permission set up corretly.  I don't have any antivirus / firewalls currently running on my machine.  Is there anything else that can I can try to fix that?

Comment: @xcdemon05: You need to use `SOCK_RAW` to do packet capturing, but as user58697 said, `SOCK_RAW` requires administrator rights, and is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548.aspx) as such: "Raw sockets offer the capability to manipulate the underlying transport, so they can be used for malicious purposes that pose a security threat. Therefore, only members of the Administrators group can create sockets of type SOCK_RAW on Windows 2000 and later".

Comment: You should use a packet capture library like [WinPCap](http://www.winpcap.org) instead of writing your own capture code.

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this:

```
#define PLATFORM_WINDOWS 1

#if defined(_WIN32)
#define PLATFORM PLATFORM_WINDOWS
#endif

#if PLATFORM == PLATFORM_WINDOWS
#include <WinSock2.h>
#endif

#pragma comment( lib, "wsock32.lib" );
#pragma comment( lib, "Ws2_32.lib" );

#include <iostream>

bool InitializeSockets()
{
#if PLATFORM == PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    WSADATA WsaData;
    int a = WSAStartup( MAKEWORD(2,2), &WsaData);
    if (a != 0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup() failed. Error %d\n", a);
        return false;
    }
#endif
    return true;
}

void ShutdownSockets()
{
#if PLATFORM == PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    WSACleanup();
#endif
}

#if PLATFORM != PLATFORM_WINDOWS
void closesocket(int socket)
{
    close(socket);
}
#endif

int GetLastSocketError()
{
#if PLATFORM == PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    return WSAGetLastError();
#else
    return errno;
#endif
}

int main()
{
    if (!InitializeSockets())
        return -1;

    int thisSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP);
    if (thisSocket == -1)
    {
        printf("socket() failed. Error %d\n", GetLastSocketError());
        ShutdownSockets();
        return -1;
    }

    sockaddr_in bindaddr = {0};
    bindaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    // set bindaddr.sin_addr.s_addr to the desired local IP that you want to sniff from...

    if (bind(thisSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&bindaddr, sizeof(bindaddr)) == -1)
    {
        printf("bind() failed. Error %d\n", GetLastSocketError());
        closesocket(thisSocket);
        ShutdownSockets();
        return -1;
    }

    u_long optVal = 1;
    if (setsockopt(thisSocket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, (char *)&optVal, sizeof(optVal)) == -1)
    {
        printf("setsockopt() failed. Error %d\n", GetLastSocketError());
        closesocket(thisSocket);
        ShutdownSockets();
        return -1;
    }

#if PLATFORM == PLATFORM_WINDOWS    
    DWORD inn = RCVALL_ON;
    if (WSAIoctl(thisSocket, SIO_RCVALL, &inn, sizeof(inn), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1)
    {
        printf("WSAIoctl() failed. Error %d\n", GetLastSocketError());
        closesocket(thisSocket);
        ShutdownSockets();
        return -1;
    }
#endif

    u_char Buffer[0xffff];

    while(1)
    {
        int len = recvfrom(thisSocket, (char*)Buffer, sizeof(Buffer), NULL, 0, 0);
        if (len == -1)
        {
            printf("recvfrom() failed. Error %d\n", GetLastSocketError());
            closesocket(thisSocket);
            ShutdownSockets();
            return -1;
        }

        printIpPacket(Buffer, len);
    }

    closesocket(thisSocket);
    ShutdownSockets();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It isn't compiling :( VS doesn't recognize a number of the MACROS, including SIO_RCVALL, IP_HDRINCL, and RCVALL_ON.  Also getting some compilation errors about recvfrom not being able to convert par 2 from u_char [65535] to char*, but that doesn't seem like a huge deal.

Comment: You need to `#include` the relevant header files, like `Mstcpip.h`, `Ws2tcpip.h` and `winsock2.h`. Next time you get errors about unknown symbols, read the relevant [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com) documentation.